# django rest framework SerializerMethodField bizarre behaviour

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When two serializer classes declare a SerializerMethodField with same name, like this:

```
class APIProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(APIProfileSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

    def get_image(self, instance):

        if instance.image:
            return self.request.build_absolute_uri(location=instance.image.url)
        return None

    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    # other ProfileSerializer fields

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('image')



class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(ProfileSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

    def get_image(self, instance):

        if instance.image:
            return self.request.build_absolute_uri(location=instance.image.url)
        return None

    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    # other ProfileSerializer fields

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('image')
```

the code

```
serializer = APIProfileSerializer(instance=request.user, request=request)
return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

crashes with the following traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 174, in get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in get_response
>       response = response.render()
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 160, in render
>       self.content = self.rendered_content
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 71, in rendered_content
>       ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 675, in render
>       context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 618, in get_context
>       raw_data_put_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'PUT', request)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 540, in get_raw_data_form
>       content = renderer.render(serializer.data, accepted, context)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 503, in data
>       ret = super(Serializer, self).data
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 239, in data
>       self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 472, in to_representation
>       ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/superhq_rest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1645, in to_representation
>       return method(value)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/vhosts/superhq_backend/account/serializers.py", line 32, in get_image
>       return self.request.build_absolute_uri(location=instance.image.url)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

( my first question is: how to make traceback more readable in markdown? =) )

It's like `request` hasn't been passed to serializer

however, this

```
serializer = ProfileSerializer(instance=request.user, request=request)
return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

and this

```
serializer = APIProfileSerializer(instance=request.user,request=request)
_data = serializer.data,
return Response(data=_data)
```

work fine...

Debugging show that BOTH APIProfileSerializer and ProfileSerializer are called, and the crash is caused by calling `get_image` in `ProfileSerializer` without passing `request` to it

So, the question is: WTF?! I didn't call this serializer! I never even mentioned it in my views! How and for what reason is it being called?

I stick to the latter code piece to solve this problem, but there's got to be a better way! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that DRF's ImageField returns full URL if `request` has been provided to serializer context, so there is no need for explicit URL construction. Clean and elegant (requires source studying though - official documentation does not mention this)

Answer (score 1):

I kinda solved it like this:

changed

```
if instance.image:
```

to

```
if instance.image and self.request:
```

so these under-the-hood `get_image()` calls without a proper `self.request` do not cause crashes anymore.

Still, it would be great to know why all of the above takes place